# How to avoid ANR From an app when it is not in the foreground?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog, android-background

I am trying to find a solution for Application Not Responding (ANR) error when my app is in background. I want any ANR not to occur when my app is not in foreground.
How this can be achieved?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have not mentioned what type of activity you are doing in background of app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Google docs:

Android will display the ANR dialog for a particular application when it detects one of the following conditions:

- No response to an input event (such as key press or screen touch events) within 5 seconds.
- A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds.

After that be sure to not do blocking/long operations on the UiThread/MainThread even if the App is in background.